# Foreach loop returns only last value

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel and i get an array from the view where the input I want is separated by period 
I have this code:

```
$addedskills = Input::get('addskills'); //array of values sep by period
   $addedskillsarray=explode(".",$addedskills); //gettin each value
    //array_slice() to remove the first element of the array bcz it's empty
   foreach(array_slice($addedskillsarray, 1) as $addnewskills)
      $skills = new Skill();
      $skills->skill_name = $addnewskills;
      $user->skills()->save($skills);
   }
```

//Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#addlanguages").val(""); 
   $("#addskills").val(""); 
   $("#btnaddskills").click(function(){ 
      var skilltxt=$("#slctskill").val();
      $("#addbtnskill").append('<button name="newskill" type="button" class="btn lng-btn">'+skilltxt+'<span class="badge badge-danger custom-badge"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span></button>'); 
      $("#addskills").val(inputvalueskills+'.'+skilltxt);
      var inputvalueskills=$("#addskills").val(); 
   });
});
```

The problem is it returns only the last value of the array

Comment: Can you show a representative example of your $addedskillsarray?

Comment: what @zoubida13 said plus I would move the array_slice call out of the loop for better readability

Comment: @zoubida13 i use this script to get the value that are passed to a hidden input

Comment: '$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addlanguages").val("");
        $("#addskills").val("");
        $("#btnaddskills").click(function(){
             var skilltxt=$("#slctskill").val();
            
             $("#addbtnskill").append('<button name="newskill" type="button" class="btn lng-btn">'+skilltxt+'<span class="badge badge-danger custom-badge"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span></button>');
               
             $("#addskills").val(inputvalueskills+'.'+skilltxt);
            var inputvalueskills=$("#addskills").val();
        });'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try array_filter here

```
$addedskills = Input::get('addskills');
   $addedskillsarray= array_filter(explode(".",$addedskills));

   foreach($addedskillsarray as $addnewskills)
      $skills = new Skill();
      $skills->skill_name = $addnewskills;
      $user->skills()->save($skills);
   }
```